# Can't use swi-prolog in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, prolog, swi-prolog

When I launch the prolog view, the console shows:

org.cs3.prolog.connector.process.PrologProcessException:
org.cs3.prolog.connector.process.PrologProcessStartException: Failed to start the Prolog process
!The path to the prolog executable is invalid

For which I am not finding anything on google, which seems weird to me tbh. Only places I got where:
https://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/docs_archive/v0.x/platform_notes

that I cannot manage to understand if it's related to my proble, and

http://prodevtools.sourceforge.net/v0.1.1/configuration.html

which seems to be from an older version. So, any help on how to fix this problem? I'm spending way too much time trying to use prolog, 2nd method I use already (after trying and failing to install ciao).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem due to the inappropriate configuration of PDP into Eclipse with SWI-PL. Actually, one needs to address to the Prolog executable, deservedly.

The issue was disappeared, by taking below instructions into account:

1- Install *SWI-PL*.

2- Look up this address in eclipse: **Window > Preferences > PDT > Prolog Processes**

3- Check SWI Prolog and press Edit

4- Browse **swipl.exe** file from its corresponding address (default is: C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\swipl.exe)

5- Press Ok